# Main.bundle.infoDictionary returns me empty Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, module, nsbundle

In my project I have a seperate module for networking code where I need to set the version number of the app in the header of each request.

During initalization call of the networkmanager `Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"]`since the infoDictionary is empty although the Main bundle is loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
if let version = bundle.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
        print(version)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following extension

```
extension Bundle {
    var versionNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
    }
    var buildNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
Bundle.main.versionNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an accessor now, "object(forInfoDictionaryKey:()" which gives you this:

```
if let version = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey:"CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String {
  print(version)
}
```

It's acually longer though.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String {
    print(version)
}
```

You can try this.